# iPhone like picker control using Javascript\Jquery

Tags: javascript, controls, using, picker

I am looking for iPhone-like "picker" control which can be used in the web. 
Without using any third party control or Flash\silverlight. Only HTML,Style sheet,javascript\jquery etc. are allowed.

I will appreciate if anyone helps me.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Wondering if someone has an answer to this question. I'm interested in the answer as well. Any third party control in javascript/jQuery will do.

Answer (score 1):

*Severals years late, but here's an answer anyway!*

**I found this while looking for other jquery ui plugins:**
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-iphone-ui/

I haven't used it, but it apparently supports

- menus
- row icons
- tabs
- scrollbar
- password fields
- toggle switches
- picker

Anyway,  you can likely find other (possibly better) widgets by googling.
cheers!